# Customize Picker background color and Title Color in xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, uipickerview, background-color, picker, custom-renderer

I am looking for "Highlight the Picker with **Background color** whenever it is clicked" and also "**Title Color**"

And when i click other picker the previous picker has to be change to default color, and current clicked picker has to be change color.

I tried with PickerName.BackgroundColor property in code behind, but its not working properly, sometimes its not changing. Is there any other way or how to achieve this using custom renderer or anything?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried changing background color on **Main Thread ?**

Comment: yeah, its working with that and also Focused evnent, but is this the correct way to do that? and Title Text color is not changed at all.

Comment: UI always update on main thread so it is the correct way for updating background color.

Answer (score 1):

We can change BackgroundColor in **SelectedIndexChanged** event in PCL.

```
picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
 {
     picker.BackgroundColor=Color.Red;
 };
```

**(or)**

We can achieve this through [CustomRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/).

**Example:**
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18563/custom-renderer-for-picker

**Xamarin.iOS**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uipickerview-in-xamarin-ios/

Find Override method for Picker Selection in Xamarin.iOS and put that override method in CustomRenderer and in that change the background color

Comment: is there anything for change its Title Color

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
  picker.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
  picker.TextColor=Color.Pink;
});
```

Comment: No, I asked for Title color not text color.

Comment: @Riyas can tell me which title color you want to change is it displayed in when picker opens ? or something else ?

Comment: I used following code to change the title color temporarily ,                                         


`Control.AttributedPlaceholder = new Foundation.NSAttributedString(Control.AttributedPlaceholder.Value, foregroundColor: Color.FromRgb(0,0,0).ToUIColor());`


But i need to change the color dynamically, is there any override method for picker tapped or when focused, we can change the Titile color again as i given.

Comment: Picker does not contain property for  **placeholder color** and  **title of picker is displayed as placeholder in native control** so you have done is correct and proper for changing placeholder color @Riyas

Comment: and i need it to change title color again whenever i tap the picker, for that i need override method, is there any available in custom renderer ?